# Multiply values of a dictionary (with two indices : Periods,Products) by values of a column (with one index: Products) in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

The column values are the following :

```
Products   Hours of labor per unit of product i
1                 160
2                 180
3                 120
```

Name: Hours of labor per unit, dtype: int64

The dictionary values are the following :

```
{
     (1, 1): Quantity_Produced_(1,_1), 
     (1, 2): Quantity_Produced_(1,_2), 
     (1, 3): Quantity_Produced_(1,_3), 
     (2, 1): Quantity_Produced_(2,_1), 
     (2, 2): Quantity_Produced_(2,_2), 
     (2, 3): Quantity_Produced_(2,_3), 
     (3, 1): Quantity_Produced_(3,_1), 
     (3, 2): Quantity_Produced_(3,_2), 
     (3, 3): Quantity_Produced_(3,_3)
}
```

I want to obtain the following output :

```
160 * Quantity_Produced_(1,_1) + 180 * Quantity_Produced_(1,_2) + 
120 * Quantity_Produced_(1,_3) + 160 * Quantity_Produced_(2,_1) +
180 * Quantity_Produced_(2,_2) + 120 * Quantity_Produced_(2,_3) + 
160 * Quantity_Produced_(3,_1) + 180 * Quantity_Produced_(3,_2) +
120 * Quantity_Produced_(3,_3)
```

[image: 1]

**My Code**

```
P = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("Quantity Produced", ((Periods,Products)
for Periods,Products in parameters.index),lowBound=0, cat='Integer') for Periods in parameters_1.index:
hl = parameters_4['Hours of labor per unit']
y = parameters_1['Working hours']
pd.Series(P)
pd.Series(W)
prob += pulp.lpSum (pd.Series(P)*hl) <= pd.Series(W)*y
```

Comment: the edit link is available under the post.

Comment: please don't post as link or photo or text, post it as snippet, and use repos only to provide whole code and post only the smallest reproducible example